# How to pass the nid from hook_node_view to the submit function?

Tags: 7, forms

I need one button at the end of one content type view form. This button should redirect the user to another page.

I have something like the following code:

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

    if ($node->type == 'my_type') {
            $form = drupal_get_form('redirect_button_form');
            $node->content['redirect_button'] = $form;
            //$node->nid is the data I need in the submit function
    }
 }

function redirect_button_form($form, &$form_submit) {
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Redirect button text'),
    );
    return $form;
}

function redirect_button_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $path = 'mypath';
    $options = ****I need the nid here;
    drupal_goto($path,$options );
}
```

How can I pass the nid from the hook_node_view to the submit function?

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Comment: a pleasure help you ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the code with comments inside:

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

if ($node->type == 'YOUR_NODE_TYPE') {
  //adding the nid to the drupal_get_form()
  $form = drupal_get_form('redirect_button_form', $node->nid);
  $node->content['redirect_button'] = $form;
 }
}

//see the 3th param ($nid)
function redirect_button_form($form, &$form_submit, $nid) {
    //adding a hiddin field with the nid
    $form['hidden-item'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $nid,
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('New Item'),
    );
    return $form;
}

function redirect_button_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $path = 'node/';
    //here your nid
    $options = $form_state['values']['hidden-item'];
    $path .= $options . '/edit';
    drupal_goto($path);

}
```

Comment: a pleasure, and good luck in your projects

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use form here. Just use [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) with the button name and the link path.

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

if ($node->type == 'my_type') {
   $node->content['redirect_button'] = array(
     '#markup' => l('Redirect button', 'yourpath/' . $node->nid);
   );
    }
}
```

Comment: I test the code but don't works for me.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check now.